# Как сделать чтобы при клике на любую картинку она подставлялась фоном (background-size: contain) в div с классом "box"

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>hw_js_dz_6</title>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="Image">
        <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="Image">
        <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="Image">
        <img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="Image">
        <img src="img/img5.jpg" alt="Image">
        <img src="img/img6.jpg" alt="Image">
        <img src="img/img7.jpg" alt="Image">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var box = document.querySelector(".box");
var el = document.getElementById(".gallery");
el.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

  if(e.target.tagName == 'IMG'){

   var src = e.target.getAttribute('src');

   box.style.backgroundImage = src;

   }

});
```

Должно быть примерно как-то так, попробуй поиграться с срцшниками если не заработает, написал на вскидку, могут быть не точности)
через jquery чуток проще

Там в коде больше описана логика, так что пробуйте